# TinyMCE editor Visual view in Wordpress shows HTML code

Tags: html, wordpress, tinymce

My Wordpress texteditor shows `HTML` code in the visual editor and in the text editor it shows some `html` entities instead of the HTML tags.

Do I have to configure the `TinyMCE text editor`?

**Refer Visual studio image.**

[image]

**Refer Text editor image.**

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue with my wordpress website.

Comment: I was working with a framework where I had something wrong in the code, I actually don't know anymore what I did wrong.